# Mouse out event not working properly in JavaScript D3

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, d3.js, react-hooks

I am working with **D3** Charts, and by all work I have completed the chart and did some enhancement as well.

**What I am doing**

1. I have one function which shows tooltip, whenever I hover over any bar I am showing some info to  the user.
2. My chart shows live data, so if any new data is coming it automatically creates a new bar.
3. SO when I hover over any bar then data is showing fine and perfect [image: in this image it is totally fine]

**My issue**

4. So as I mentioned above in my case the data comes after some interval continuously, so I am getting data and adding it to previous data
5. The issue is when i Hover the last bar the tooltip shows fine, and when the new data comes so now two tooltips showing and it goes on and on [image: It shows like this]

But in my coding I am writing code to remove the tooltip on **mouseout**, but still getting this issue

**My code**

This is what I am doing

```
.on("mousemove", function (event, d) {
    // this whole code is when I hover that perticular bar
    d3.select(this)
      .transition()
      .duration("50")
      .attr("opacity", 0.6)
      .attr("x", (a) => xScaleBars(a.timeline) - 3)
      .attr("width", xScaleBars.bandwidth() + 6)
      .style("filter", "url(#glow)");

    div.transition().duration(50).style("opacity", 1);
    div
      .html(
        `</text><text"></br> value :  ${d.dataToShow}
        <br/>
        </text><text"></br> Month :  ${d.month}
        `
      )

      .style("left", event.pageX - 58 + "px")
      .style("top", event.pageY - 140 + "px");
  })
```

This above code is when I hove rover

**Below is the code when I do mouseout**

```
 .on("mouseout", function (d, i) {
    // this is when I move cursor out of that bar
    d3.select(this)
      .transition()
      .duration("50")
      .attr("width", xScaleBars.bandwidth())
      .attr("x", (a) => xScaleBars(a.timeline))
      .style("filter", "none")
      .attr("opacity", "1");
    div.transition().duration("50").style("opacity", 0);
  })
```

- I have tried display none as well as visibility property, but nothing works
- I don't know what I am doing wrong
- is My code right or wrong this also I am not getting properly

**I have put all of my code in code sandbox** [Please have a look](https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-snow-qirc9?file=/src/App.js)

**PS: I am using use Effect with set Timeout for each 1 second to make it update every second**

I have checked all the related suggestion by stack overflow, but none helped me out may be I am wrong but I did not found the solution.

**Edit / Update**

The answer suggested below is not working, if I have more than once chart
I used `d3.selectAll(".tooltipCHart").remove();`

So when there are two charts on hover of first chart's bar it shows tooltip, but when I hover over the other chart it is not showing

[Please have a look here](https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-babycat-5mj46?file=/src/chart2.js)

here in above code sandbox in first chart it does not show tooltip but in second it is showing

Answer (score 1):

Vivek, I have gone through the code and found out that most of the code written is fine. Besides that the reason of multiple tooltips is that you are rendering everything whenever data changes, so you are appending the tooltip div everytime, it means below code will execute multiple times which display multiple tooltips in case where our code did not perform mouseout execution. You can check this by inspecting elements.

```
var div = d3
      .select("body")
      .append("div")
      .attr("class", "tooltipCHart")
      .style("opacity", 0);
```

Simple solution will be to remove all the tooltips before appending a new one.

```
 d3.selectAll(".tooltipCHart").remove();
```

It will resolve the issue of multiple tooltips.

But for your chart my confusion is whether is it a good idea to show tooltip or not as the data is always moving toward left so it will be difficult to keep the tooltip for long time.

Comment: Hi @jasdeep I tried what you suggested, but I got one issue in that, when I am showing only one chart that that `.remove()` is working fine but when there are multiple charts it is causing issue, the issue is it is showing tooltip for one chart only, I have prepared a Code sandbox please have a look https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-babycat-5mj46?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Hi @viveksingh It is completely a new question and should not be asked here and should be asked as a new question. The reason you are facing this issue because we are removing all the tooltips and we should restrict that behavior only for that particular chart. Please see the this sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-snowflake-dyyiu?file=/src/chart2.js

Comment: Hi @jasdeepSingh I have asked a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70937326/multiple-tooltips-not-showing-correctly-in-react

please have a look if you can help