# Multiple tooltips not showing correctly in react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, d3.js, react-hooks

I am working with react D3 charts, and I have created charts and it is working fine.

**What I have done**

- I have several charts which are updating with in some time intervals, something like live data
- So here to achieve this I out use effect and updating my charts every second, and my data in charts updates correctly.
- I have given one tooltip on hover over the the bar, so that user can check the data for each bar or line.

**Using below code to show the tooltip**

```
.on("mousemove", function (event, d) {
    // this whole code is when I hover that perticular bar
    d3.select(this)
      .transition()
      .duration("50")
      .attr("opacity", 0.6)
      .attr("x", (a) => xScaleBars(a.timeline) - 3)
      .attr("width", xScaleBars.bandwidth() + 6)
      .style("filter", "url(#glow)");

    div.transition().duration(50).style("opacity", 1);
    div
      .html(
        `</text><text"></br> value :  ${d.dataToShow}
        <br/>
        </text><text"></br> Month :  ${d.month}
        `
      )

      .style("left", event.pageX - 58 + "px")
      .style("top", event.pageY - 140 + "px");
  })
  .on("mouseout", function (d, i) {
    // this is when I move cursor out of that bar
    d3.select(this)
      .transition()
      .duration("50")
      .attr("width", xScaleBars.bandwidth())
      .attr("x", (a) => xScaleBars(a.timeline))
      .style("filter", "none")
      .attr("opacity", "1");
    div.transition().duration("50").style("opacity", 0);
  })
```

**Issue I am facing**

- The issue is when I hover over one chart component it shows the tooltip, and than when I hover over the other both shows at the same time. [image: It shows Like this.]
- What I am trying to do is to show the tooltip when I hover the one bar of any chart and than hide it,I tried below code

`d3.select("svg").selectAll(".tooltipCHart").remove();`

But it doesn't resolve my issue, I think I am missing some small part

[here is my code sandbox which I tried](https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-hofstadter-drrnd)

Comment: With any render you lost tooltip reference. I find a solution, but I think exist best solutions. Hide all tooltips after render:`d3.selectAll(".tooltipCHart").style("opacity", 0);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're creating a new tooltip `div` every time you re-render the chart.

A better approach is to have a hidden tooltip div in the beginning (in the render / return from your function component) and then just modify its contents and style (opacity: 1) on `mouseover` and `mouseout`. Keep track of the tooltip div using a `ref`.

See working [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-benji-lv1h9?file=/src/chart1.js) (I only modified chart1, you can make similar changes to chart2)